# How can I fetch Laravel models by matching a value on a relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a `User` model with attributes like login, ID, age, etc. Another table is `user_data` with a `residence` column, for example.

How can I get all users with a specific residence? I have this:

`User` model:

```
public function user_data()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\UserData');
}

public function FilterUser($request)
{
    if ($request->has('city')) 
    {
        $users = User::with('user_data')->where('residence', 'Warsaw')->get();        
    }

    dd($users);
}
```

`UserData` model:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
}
```

Now I get this error:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'residence' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `residence` = warsaw and `users`.`deleted_at` is null)

And another question:

If `User` is my main model, should I connect it with relationships like above? `hasMany()` or `belongsTo()`?

Comment: Make an sql squery to get it: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries

Comment: @peter as you see above I tried it a lot of times, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `whereHas()` query builder method:

```
$users = User::with('user_data') 
    ->whereHas('user_data', function($query) { 
        $query->where('residence', 'Warsaw'); 
    })
    ->get();
```

Edit - To use the value from `$request` you need to import the variable to the closure for `whereHas()`:

```
    ...
    ->whereHas('user_data', function($query) use ($request) {
        $query->where('residence', $request->city);
    })
    ...
```

Edit - A [query scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#query-scopes) may be a better approach. In the `User` model, add this method:

```
function scopeInCity($query, $city)
{
    return $query->whereHas('user_data', function($q) use ($city) {
        $q->where('residence', $city);
    });
}
```

Then you can filter all users by city (outside the model):

```
User::inCity($request->city)->get();
```

Comment: That works. But how to change Warsaw to $request->city? 
I have $request as function parameter put id doesn't work now

Comment: And the last question. I can't do something like $user->id because: 
Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance
How to do it correctly?

Comment: The `get()` method at the end of the builder returns a collection with all the users that match the query. If you just want one user, you need to pass a user ID to the `FilterUser()` method for the user you want to fetch and change `get()` to `first()`, or loop through each of the users in the collection.

Comment: I want to display all the users, but It doesnt work when I use foreach

Answer (score 0):

Use whereHas if you want to get all users that have a relationship with a specific attribute like so:

```
$users = User::whereHas('user_data', function($q) {
$q->where('residence', 'Warsaw');})->get();
```